CKEditor: Track changes with custom editor data update through API
I'm using CK-Editor 5 (React JS) with Track Changes plugin enabled.
My need is to replace a selection of text from the editor when clicked on a button.
This code exactly works as expected except only one thing. It doesn't recognize the replaced text by the "Track changes" plugin and doesn't highlight or create suggestions record which is the need of the hour.
Here is my code snippet.
const selection = this.editor.model.document.selection;
// ... other codes

this.editor.model.change(writer => {
    // other codes
    
    // Insert the new content at the selection position
    const insertPosition = selection.getFirstPosition();
    writer.insertText(newText, insertPosition);
});

Any help would be greatful.
